# How to check the latest patch version applied to magento?

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, log, version

I just applied the security patch
`PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh`

Since I have no SSH access to the web server, the provider did the work for me.
How can I check by myself if everything went alright?

I'm on Magento CE 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'm assuming you do have FTP access. When patches are applied a file named `applied.patches.list` is added in the `app/etc/` directory.

Next to that the patch is nothing more than a diff file so you can see what it should change when you open it and check in the targeted file if it is indeed changed

Comment: The file is appended to every time a patch is added as well. You can see the patch application history over the lifetime of the website and check to see if all applicable patches have been reapplied after the Magento version upgrade overwrites and removes the patched files. Helps to prevent upgrade regression errors.

Comment: is any other way to check the patch 5944 if it is not updated with the help of .sh file?Because in that case "applied.patches.list" not generated at all.

Comment: As @willem mentioned below you can check with https://shoplift.byte.nl/

Comment: Thnaks@Sander but that only verify 5344 not 5944

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread. In that case the quickest way would be to check if certain code from the patch is applied or not

Answer (score 12):

You can test successful installation of the patches (and existence of other known vulnerabilities) at https://www.magereport.com (used to be at https://shoplift.byte.nl but I've extended the checks)

Comment: I know, its been a while, but have you any feedback on how accurate magereport.com is?

Comment: I would say it is about 99% accurate. If it doesn't know, it will say "unknown".

Answer (score 6):

**Simply use SSH to check if your shop is patched**

For More information kindly visit below URL:
https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-apply-magento-patches/

> You can scan your site with magereport.com to see if a patch is installed or not. If a check comes up grey it’s possible the files that are needed for the check are relocated. Therefore it can’t see whether your shop is patched or not. No worries. Simply use SSH to check if your shop is patched.
>
> Every check that’s been installed can easily be found in the content of your shop. More specifically it’s logged in **app/etc/applied.patches.list**
>
> So you run this command **'grep'** on SSH to access the list of applied security patches:
>
> ```
> grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
> ```
>
> The output will look like this:
>
> ```
> -e 2015-04-14 08:34:22 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
> ```

Hope It's helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Great free extension for easy display all applied patches on Magento admin https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AppliedPatches