# Magento security patch 5994/6285 CE problem

Tags: error, security, patches

I have to work on a "work in progress" magento that someone else started. I have to install some patches magento added. I have no clue / way to know which patch he did install before he left but the only patch he had was 5994 EE ( we are using CE ).

When I try to install the 5994 patch i got this "errors"

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 68.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 115.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 129.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 201.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 276.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 312.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 273.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 266.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 109.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 48.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Done
```

And when i try the 6285 patch i got this (I did search about it and some people was reffering to patch 5994 wasn't installed):

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 84.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 71.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 52.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 69.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 32.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 367.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 67.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 45.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 45.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 222.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 63.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 88.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 56.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 160.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 174.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 161.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 267.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 160.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 389.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 155.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 282.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 34.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 34.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 42.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 203.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 76.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 202.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 130.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 180.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 345.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 466.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 50.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 145.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 59.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 47.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 116.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 86.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 42.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 95.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 298.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 76.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 127.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php
Done
```

Comment: If it's someone else's project,  check for the difference between above mentioned core files with a default Magento setup. Some people just love to edit the core.

Comment: I ended up just backuping evreything and install 1.9.2.1 and use the theme i made for it insteads of trying to install patches directly. Thank you for this advice tho, i know a lots of dev can do this be he shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, if patches can't be applied, check:

1. Are you using the right patch version for your Magento version?
2. Do the files that the patch fails to update present or have they been changed? Replace them with original files from your Magento version and apply the patch again

Answer (score 1):

Part of the question was which patches were already installed.

You can check the `./app/etc/applied.patches.list` file.
You will find detailed information about the patch(es) and what files have been modified.

More Information can be found here [How to check the latest patch version applied to magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/how-to-check-the-latest-patch-version-applied-to-magento)

Answer (score 0):

Before the newest patch 6788, all other patches are backward compatibility. It means all the changes are applied for only CORE files of Magento, not customization.

A list recommended patches to apply as following (sort by time desc):

SUPEE-6482 - This patch addresses two issues related to APIs and two cross-site scripting risks. - Added Aug 4, 2015

SUPEE-6285 - This patch provides protection against several types of security-related issues, including information leaks, request forgeries, and cross-site scripting. - Added Jul 7, 2015

SUPEE-5994 - This patch addresses multiple security vulnerabilities in Magento Community Edition software, including issues that can put customer information at risk. - Added May 14, 2015

SUPEE-5344 - Addresses a potential remote code execution exploit. - Added Feb 9, 2015

SUPEE-1533 - Addresses two potential remote code execution exploits. - Added Oct 3, 2014

Therefore, from my experience, there are a few things you can do as below:

1. If the old developer installed patches via command line, then you
   can see a list of applied patches via the file
   app/etc/applied.patches.list Then install missing patches (from the
   older patch to the newer patch)
2. If you don't see anything in the file app/etc/applied.patches.list
   or there is no file
       app/etc/applied.patches.list (then may be the old developer only
       uploaded changed files to that site), or you still have errors as
       commented in the question, may be you need:

   - Get a refresh Magento installation with the same version as the site you are working on.
   - Apply patches to this installation, then compare files between the new site vs the current site you are working on (checking for only core files)

As stated above, because only CORE files will be patched, so you can safely replace changed files from your new installation to the new site.

**Note**:

- Please create a backup before doing any change to your site (like
  creating a dev site to apply first, if everything is OK then apply to
  live site)
- Before there is a case when the old developer made changes directly into core files, so may be you also check about that.