# Block type in static block not working

Tags: category, static-block, list-view

On some of my websites I use this code:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

It works fine on three websites but on one website it doesn't work. I use it in a static block. This static block is displayed on the category pages.

After some testing it seems that almost every line of code with block type is not working. I tried displaying another category and such but with no luck.

Answer (score 7):

The three websites where it works probably have a bigger problem than the one where it doesn't: they do not have the recent security patch SUPEE-6788 applied.

One thing that the patch changed was that blocks to be used in CMS directives like that have to be added to a whitelist. You find this whitelist in **System > Permissions > Blocks**.

More details in this question: 
[APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables)

Comment: Last week they worked fine on the website but suddenly it stoped working. I didn't install any update in that week.

Comment: Maybe somebody else did. To be sure, check: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/how-to-check-the-latest-patch-version-applied-to-magento

Comment: I whitelisted the block and it now seems to work. So why it worked last week is unknown to me.

Comment: OMG - I tried to solve this problem the whole day now.... and the solution was so "easy". I upgraded my DEV-server from 1.8 to 1.9 and thought it had something to do with new APIs. THANK YOU!