# Mention what is the benefit of applying Connect Patches in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, security

I have some queries.

```
1.Mention what is the benefit of applying Connect Patches in Magento?
2.Why all patches are not implemented ?
3.How to check whether it is correctly installed or not ?
4.Is there any issue if magento site dont have patches?
```

Comment: are you teling about security patches ?

Comment: i asked need some answer and up-votes :)
Thanks for following me  i appreciate you.

Answer (score 5):

1. You save your store from being hacked through known exploits
2. what?
3. [How to check the latest patch version applied to magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/how-to-check-the-latest-patch-version-applied-to-magento)
4. Hacker will steal your customer data. You lose trust and money.

Comment: you have great profile . Impressed.
Thanks Fabian Schmengler.

Answer (score 2):

Re your second question:

> 2.Why all patches are not implemented?

The newest Magento version includes all patches.

- Magento 2.1.0 and 2.0.8
- Magento 1 ver 1.9.2.4  - Added Feb 23, 2016
  Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1