# How to check what suppee patches have been installed on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

there are multiple **patch** are available.
that we install in our site

i just want a **script** to find out which patch are install in my magento site.

**anyone help?**

Answer (score 2):

Like Krishna said, you can check applied.patches.list.

Also there is a good checker which helps for normal users without server details or dont know how to check.

Here: https://www.magereport.com/

You will get what you need and even more :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the applied patches `applied.patches.list` in the app/etc/ directory.
When we apply patches this files are generated automatically.

Next to that the patch is nothing more than a diff file so you can see what it should change when you open it and check in the targeted file if it is indeed changed.

Comment: i want a script to find out which patch is install in my site. if there is no applied.patches.list file

Comment: You can check the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/how-to-check-the-latest-patch-version-applied-to-magento

Comment: Or you can try this free extension https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AppliedPatches

Comment: If you install patch there will be file applied.patches.list. but still you can check your store at magereports.com or another website who can scan your store and provide details for patches

Comment: if someone delete applied.patches.list file . than how i knw which patch in stalled?

Comment: Yes we can identify. As per patch modification/description, you can see into files whether the file modified by patch changes or not.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to other people's answers Philip Jackson developped a small free module to be able to check the applied patches from the backend. It's available here: https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AppliedPatches